# Must have done something or must have something done

Tags: grammar

I got in trouble and people  said "he must have done something"
Which one is correct? " must have done something" or "must have something done " do they mean the samethng?

Answer (score 1):

They are correct but completely different. The first one means high probability of a past event seen from the Present. The second  one refers to the necessity of having something done by someone. The second construction  is a specific example of the Passive Voice.
For example, I can't start my car. It must have broken down. I must have it fixed.

Comment: +1 for a correct answer. But it would help if you gave some examples of the use of each of them e.g. *The service has improved, they must have done something* and *The roof's falling in, I must have something done (to fix it)*.